# Говорим по-старорусски

Tags: этимология

Хлеб в зерне — жито. Кувшин для кваса — жбан. А как по-старорусски можно назвать «старинные стихи»?

Answer (score 4):

Смотря какой период подразумеваете под старым, в 17 веке было слово ВИРШИ
http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%88 
1. первоначально — духовные, а затем и светские стихи в России XVI-XVIII веков; силлабические двустишья, скрепленные рифмой ◆ Украинским бурсакам и ученым принадлежит первые попытки писать рифмованные стихи (вирши) на церковнославянском языке, и именно от этих вирш в XVII и в начале XVIII века ведет свою родословную вся русская поэзия (разумеется, не простонародная). Н. С. Трубецкой, «Общеславянский элемент в русской культуре», 1928 г. (цитата из Национального корпуса русского языка), среди русских поэтов-виршеписцев стоит назвать таких поэтов, как Симеон Полоцкий, Сильвестр Медведев, Феофан Прокопович,  а также, позднее, уже в XVIII веке, Антиох Кантемир, создававшие различные произведения в жанре силлабической поэзии.

Comment: В украинском языке "вирш" (вiрш) и сейчас переводится как "стихотворение"

Comment: @Надюшка, а «жито» – как «рожь».

Answer (score 1):

Понятия стиха в древнерусский период еще не сложилось. Были былины, предания, "слова" ("Слово о полку Игоревом"). Само "Слово", кстати, написано неким особом способом, которое вполне можно считать образцом какого-то неизвестного нам ныне "стиха". Вероятно современники как-то его называли. Но современных названий ему не придумали. Так и говорят: *Стих "Слова (о полку)"*.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно , в Древней Руси стихи назывались *песнями* , аналогично как в Европе . Те песни не пели , как музыкальные , а просто зачитывали . Но это суждение предположительное , а не утвердительное .